# Are there any alternatives to getting the rootViewController besides through app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, instance, multiple-instances, rootview

I am working on a deep linking app where I need to assign the delegate of my deep link manager to my subclass of the tabbarcontroller

How can I return the root tabbarcontroller from inside the subclass of the tab bar controller?

Here is the app del function, where i call [TMDeeplinkManager searchForPodcast...] [self.mainTabController getMainTabBarController] i would like to change that to

[TMMainTabBarController mainTabBarController]

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    NSNumber *collectionId = [url host];
    NSString *episodeTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [url lastPathComponent]];

    [TMDeeplinkManager searchForPodcastWithCollectionID:collectionId
                                                  title:episodeTitle
                                            andDelegate:[self.mainTabController getMainTabBarController]];

    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

This is the The subclass of the tabbarcontroller, How do I return the root view controller in the instancetype? without using the app del?

```
@interface TMMainTabBarController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) id selectedItem;

@end

@implementation TMMainTabBarController {
    TMMainTabBarController *mainTabBarController;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)didSelectEpisode:(TMPodcastEpisode *)episode {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] ;
    TMAudioPlayerViewController *audioPlayerViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TMAudioPlayerViewController"];

    audioPlayerViewController.episode = episode;

    UINavigationController *mainNavController = self.viewControllers[0];
    [mainNavController pushViewController:audioPlayerViewController animated:true];

}

-(void)setMainTabBarController:(TMMainTabBarController *)tabBarController {
    mainTabBarController = tabBarController;
}

-(TMMainTabBarController *)getMainTabBarController {
    return mainTabBarController;
}

+(instancetype)mainTabBarController {

    return self.mainTabBarController;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIViewController *root = self;
while (root.parentViewController != nil) {
    root = root.parentViewController;
}
```

//viola !